# Facebook JavaScript SDK (Reference Error)

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

so I'm attempting to incorporate my Facebook SDK into a Javascript HTTP request and I'm placing the following code before my functions.http.onRequest

```
// Facebook initializaiton
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId            : '206379769769774',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

however, when I try to run the code I get the following error

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/qd/3sk3cm452h9284yk1bc59y8r0000gn/T/fbfn_68959Wo0i1Y3DJWvx/index.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:32:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to use the JavaScript SDK server side (with Node.js) - there is now window, because there is no browser. Take a look at the docs to find SDKs for Node.js: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks